# jQuery refresh var from different functions

Tags: jquery, global-variables

Let's say I got this code:

```
<div id="mydiv"></div>
<div id="click">click</div>

<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
var time = new Date().getTime();

function jo(){
    $('#mydiv').html(time);
}

$("#click").click(function(){
    jo();
    time.refresh();
});
</script>
```

As you can see I try to refresh the var `time` from a function (click) with `time.refresh();` but it's not working. How could I do this? PS: I dont really need the current second onclick it's just an example

Comment: you need this http://jsfiddle.net/vdLwvmxp/57/?

Comment: Thanks :D But can't accept because it's a comment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your script tag :

```
var time = new Date().getTime();

function jo(){
    $('#mydiv').html(time);
}

function refresh()
{
    return new Date().getTime();
}
$("#click").click(function(){
    jo();
    time=refresh();
});
```

or if you not need `refresh()` then just `time=new Date().getTime();`

[Demo in Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/62jgvadk/1/)

Answer (score 0):

How about you can do this without using refresh function

```
var time;
function jo(){
    $('#mydiv').html(time);
}

$("#click").click(function(){
    time = new Date().getTime();
    jo();
});
```

Comment: Nice solution too but kupendra was faster ^^